# Is there any way that we can check mouse right click undo event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
eventTarget.addEventListener("cut", event) {{
//Save button should be disable
});

//Above is the code for cut event

//Similarly, I tried for undo event but it's not working
eventTarget.addEventListener("undo", event) {{
//Save button should be enable
});
```

Basically i want to check if i cut the whole text from textarea then Save button should be disable.
If i selected paste or undo option from the mouse right click then Save button should be enable.

If anyone know how to do for mouse undo event then please help me ( paste event is working by above
way but undo event is not working in the similar way)

Waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to listen for the `input` event instead and decide if the Save button should be shown based on content? `cut`, `copy`, and `paste` are clipboard events; `undo` is unrelated to clipboards and has no event associated with it.

Comment: But, I have to check on undo, rest all(cut,copy, paste) are working properly. I tried removeEventListener() function also but this also not working for undo part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `input` event to detect those actions (there is no input event for copying because it doesn't change the content):

```js
const textInput = document.getElementById("text-input");
textInput.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
  switch (ev.inputType) {
    case "historyUndo":
      console.log("The user undid an action.");
      break;
    case "insertFromPaste":
      console.log("The user pasted something.");
      break;
    case "deleteByCut":
      console.log("The user cut something.");
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="Type here">
```

Comment: This thing is not working for textarea. I needed to check cut, paste and undo on textarea field

Comment: Right, I forgot how useful `inputType` is! @TechnicalAP How is it “not working” for textareas? See the [documentation for `inputType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType). You can definitely listen for several event types.

Comment: @SebastianSimon `input` events are only fired for `<input>` elements and elements with `contenteditable`.

Comment: @D.Pardal That isn’t true at all. They are fired on `<textarea>`s, too. Why would they not be?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I tested and it didn't work, but now I checked the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#events-inputevents) and it says it should work on `<textarea>` elements too. Maybe I tested it wrong or Firefox doesn't support it.

Comment: @D.Pardal Firefox Nightly 86.0a1 definitely supports it.